# Call many Observable if operator

Tags: angular

I'm with a problem .. I have a flow that does the following:

1. Create a file
2. If there is a configuration variable set to true (for example,
   `weekday = true` call a service on my server and sign a document
3. Upload the file to a server through a service.

As I said in step 2, only if the variable is `true`, you must call that service, if it were `false`, you should do step 3, the problem is that I do not know how to call several `Observables` at once and also condition them.

I have seen that with `mergeMap` I can make calls in parallel, but this does not work in my case since I must verify if the variable exists before I can call a service or another.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this pipe extract will be of some help. If var is true then make an HTTP request and pipe the response to the map operator. If there's an HTTP error it will pipe null. If the var is false it will pipe the value in the of statement to the map operator.

```
mergeMap((var) => 
  if (var === true) {
    return this.myService.doSomeHttpRequest().pipe(
    catchError(() => {
      return of(null)
    })
  ) else {
      return of('something')
  }
)),
filter(res => res != null),
map(res => {
  if (res === 'something') {
  } else
  }      
})
```

This is coded freehand, sorry for any missing brackets and things like that but it should get you on the right route. If you want the pipe to not pass anything to map then you could consider using the `filter` operator. This will block the pipe from executing anything further.

Comment: You can avoid the return of(null) and the filter by returning `EMPTY` ;)

Comment: It does not work for me, the filter throws me error :(

Comment: i missed a comma try now, also import filter operator